# установить gulp с помощью notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Как установить gulp с помощью notepad++ ? открываю плагин NppConsole в notepad++  в папке проекта  куда мне нужно установить а  там адрес папки notepad++. как поменять адрес ?

Comment: через git bash gui получилось

Comment: если Ваш комментарий является решением, укажите его в поле ответа и отметьте решением.